# What is an efficient way of inserting hundreds of records into an SQLite table using Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I have a CSV file with hundreds of data, I want to insert everything into my SQLite DB in my Django app. Inputting each value one by one will be a complete waste of time. What is a more efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in this case, is to use the bulk_create.

From the doc:

> bulk_create(objs, batch_size=None, ignore_conflicts=False)

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are), and returns created objects as a list, in the same order as provided:

Link to doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that